# Automatic file backup in Texstudio

Tags: texstudio

Is it possible to set up Texstudio such that it makes a backup of each LaTeX file it opens before any edit?

Comment: I don’t think this is possible with TeXstudio but depending on the OS you surely can setup a script that does this upon opening the file from the system (and not with the Open File dialog within TeXstudio). TeXstudio however supports SVN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this via scripting (Macros -> Edit Macros ...)

[image]

Note, that TXS will ask you to confirm the writing of the file because automatic writing of files from a script may pose a secuity hole.

If you like, you can improve the script, e.g. to prevent that an existing backup is overwritten. You may also be interested in [this related solution](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/524/). But as stated there, you might consider using a version control system instead of creating multiple copies of files.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give a link to abs's of using version control with Texstudio usable by a newb?