# Automatic file backup in Texstudio with time

Tags: texstudio

Can we make backup using date and time in Texstudio using Macros.

i.e. can we make backup of "1.tex" file with "1.tex.1-1-2016-3-30.bak" extension. where the date-time should be the time of opening file. This should not affect the previous backup file.

If we can do that then it will help to go to the specific date's edited contain.

creating backup without time is possible and the process is here.
[Automatic file backup in Texstudio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131485/automatic-file-backup-in-texstudio/299256#299256)

Thank you.

Comment: as suggested in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131485/automatic-file-backup-in-texstudio/299256#299256 it's best if you used a CVS. the easiest to use is `git`  or you could just put your files in Dropbox. DB has a built-in versioning system and allows rollbacks.

Comment: You should use Dropbox. In a free account, you will have access to 30 days of version history, and those revisions will have timestamps. Everything is automated—just press Ctrl+S more often! (It should be an innate reflex anyway.) Sadly, some of my friends lost some precious edits due to TeXStudio crashing, so if you are afraid you can forget to run the script or if you think TeXStudio is unstable (hint: the answer starts with a “y”), use Dropbox and do not forget that you have only one month of history.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to, you can do this with a script, e.g. see [this example](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Scripts/#periodic-auto-save-all-documents-under-a-new-name).

However, as already mentioned before, you should really consider using a version control system instead.