# Please help me write a macro to save file in "D:\latex\test_ddmmyy.tex" in TeXStudio?

Tags: macros, texstudio

I want to make a macro in TeXStudio to save a tex file under the name `test_ddmmyy.tex` (`ddmmyy` is current day, month, year) in the path `D:\latex\test_ddmmyy.tex`. Can you help me?

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear to me what you are asking. Do you want to write some data to a file? Do you want to just create the file? Do you want to move the file you are compiling to the specified path? What part are you having trouble with? Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the result and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: I have a new file: I want to save it with name  test_ddmmyy.tex (ddmmyy is current day,month,year) in "D:\latex" by a macro script in TeXStudio.

Comment: Hope you want to enable `autobackup` procedure in `TeXStudio`? Is that correct?

Comment: I searched for autobackup from @MadyYuvi and found this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131485/automatic-file-backup-in-texstudio which may be a good start for your idea

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
%SCRIPT
var d = new Date();
var nn = "_"+ d.getFullYear()+"_"+ d.getMonth()+"_"+ d.getUTCDay()+".tex";
var fn = editor.fileName().replace(/.tex$/, nn);

app.fileSaveAs(fn);
```

This will open the save as dialog when you close a file. You can change the trigger however you want. 
http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION33 <- See event triggers, or use your own trigger.

[image: Code]